# What is the application of 'align to page and align to margin' in word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In the Page Layout tab there are align options. When you open it there are several options, for example, *align to  page* and *align to margin*.

I select a picture and choose this option but nothing happens. What are their applications?

Comment: What do you mean 'what are their applications'?

Comment: @zain.ali I mean application of align to page and align to margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What are the "align to page" and "align to margin" options?

These options are used to decide you want to align the object relative to the page margins or relative to the very edge of the page.

You select either `align to page` or `align to margin` **before** selecting another `align` operation.

---

#### Align to page example

- Select `align to page`
- Then select `align left`
- Result -> Aligned to the **left side of the page**

---

#### Align to margin example

- Select `align to margin`
- Then select `align left`
- Result -> Aligned to the **left margin**

---

#### Warning

Aligning to the edge of the page may mean that the page will not print correctly (not all printers can print right to the edge of a page).

---

#### Further reading

- [Positioning Objects in Microsoft Word 2007](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/14248.aspx)
- [Word 2013 Arranging Objects](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/word2013/22)

Answer (score 0):

To see the difference first you create an text box. Select align to margin and left align then you will see it will in the left margin border figure 1. Again select align to page and select left align it will be in the border of the page not in the margin. fig2.

[image]